# Consulta de banco no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta no Postgre com a seguinte query:

```
SELECT t3.desc_serv,
       t3.nm_serv,
       t1.nm_usu,
       count(t2.id_atend) TOTAL_ATENDIMENTO
FROM usuarios t1
INNER JOIN historico_atendimentos t2 ON t1.id_usu = t2.id_usu
INNER JOIN servicos t3 ON t2.id_serv = t3.id_serv
WHERE t2.dt_fim::text LIKE '%2013-10%'
GROUP BY t1.nm_usu, t3.desc_serv, t3.nm_serv, t3.id_serv, t1.id_usu
```

No MySQL essa mesma consulta estava fazendo apenas assim:

```
SELECT t3.desc_serv,
       t3.nm_serv,
       t1.nm_usu,
       count(t2.id_atend) TOTAL_ATENDIMENTO
FROM usuarios t1
INNER JOIN historico_atendimentos t2 ON t1.id_usu = t2.id_usu
INNER JOIN servicos t3 ON t2.id_serv = t3.id_serv
WHERE t2.dt_fim LIKE '%2012-06%'
GROUP BY t3.id_serv, t1.id_usu
```

Não entendo porque mas no Postgre para funcionar "certo" preciso deixar o `group by` como está, mas se deixo igual do MySQL que é como preciso gera erro, informando que preciso adicionar os outros campos do select no group.

> ERRO:  coluna "t3.desc_serv" deve aparecer na cláusula GROUP BY ou ser utilizada em uma função de agregaçãoLINE 1: SELECT  t3.desc_serv,

Answer (score 4):

O `GROUP BY` do mysql não segue a risca o padrão sql ou seja oferece uma flexibilidade maior não sendo necessario especificar todas a colunas do `from list` no `group by` como mostra a documentação. [mysql - group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause
>
> O MySQL extende o uso do GROUP BY isso significa que o SELECT pode fazer referência a colunas não agregadas não listas na clausula GROUP BY

Answer (score 3):

Isto acontece porque a resolução do `GROUP BY` no *MySQL* não é ortogonal. Todas as colunas que são incluídas na seleção em que há uma operação de agregação devem ser indicadas para o agrupamento.

Isto é um comportamento peculiar do *MySQL* que está discutido [aqui](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2010/03/10/mysql-standard-group-by/) (texto em inglês). Entretanto, a normativa padrão de todo e qualquer banco é exatamente o comportamento do *Postgres*.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t3.desc_serv,
       t3.nm_serv,
       t1.nm_usu,
       count(t2.id_atend) TOTAL_ATENDIMENTO
FROM usuarios t1
INNER JOIN historico_atendimentos t2 ON t1.id_usu = t2.id_usu
INNER JOIN servicos t3 ON t2.id_serv = t3.id_serv
WHERE t2.dt_fim::text LIKE '%2013-10%'
GROUP BY t3.desc_serv,
         t3.nm_serv,
         t1.nm_usu
```

O GROUP bY deve repetir a linha do select